# Choosing a convertible laptop

Tags: tablet, mini-pc

I am looking for a tablet/convertible pc for my aunt and I am undecided what to get. The main usage would be navigation and Word processing, occasionally some light photoshop/illustrator work.

I got interesting offers for a [Microsoft Surface Pro 3](https://www.cnet.com/products/microsoft-surface-pro-3/) - i5 model (used, 2 y.o.), a new [Asus T300Chi](https://www.asus.com/2-in-1-PCs/ASUS_Transformer_Book_T300_Chi/) and a used [Samsung Galaxy Tab Pro S](http://www.samsung.com/global/galaxy/galaxy-tab-pro-s/), respectively $340 the first one and $390 each for the Asus and the Samsung devices.

Looking at the specifications, I would definitely go for the Surface or the Samsung tab, however I am worried it could turn out to be a bad investment as the battery easily degrades and cannot be replaced; being already 2 years old, the expected remaining lifetime is quite limited.

Requirements would be at least 4GB of RAM, 64+GB of hard disk storage, possibly SSD, and 11-12 inches of screen size. Except WiFi, everything else is just a plus (BT, full-size USB ports, stylus, etc.). Budget-wise my limit is $450 including shipping, even though for used items I prefer to see them in person to run hardware tests.

Anyway, what would be your suggestions? Thank you

Comment: So, what are your requirements like in terms of battery life, weight, connectivity (WiFi, BT, USB), etc? Any nice to have features that you want? I assume you're looking for US shipping, and your budget is less than 400 USD?

Comment: I edited the question adding some hardware specifications. A nice to have feature would be a stylus supported by Photoshop/Illustrator

Comment: The light Photoshop/Illustrator seems to imply you'll need an x86 based computer, unless you're fine using the rather handicapped mobile apps. Is that correct?

Comment: Why that? An Intel I-series or a M-series x64 processor should be able to run Adobe suite quite smoothly.